# Rails 3.1 + Mongoid, Embbed model with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm learning mongodb and rails right now... I have two collection, User and Event

Both User and Event models can have multiple Address, can i use the same model with different views? Or ill need to have two more models???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep only one `Address` model. Simply use polymorphism [as described here](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-1.html).

Comment: +1 thank you... this is what i looking for.. need to read the docs with more attention :)